# Why does my jQuery theme make the calendar widget mess up in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jquery-ui

I'm developing a facebook-based jquery theme but I'm having some trouble getting the calendar widget to look right in IE.

[image: http://i55.tinypic.com/1zzswi.png]

Here's the demo page:

http://ilsken.com/fbui/

In IE8 the calendar widgets dates all get squished to the left and just look plain wrong.
The only part the CSS I can imagine causing this are here:

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    background: #D8DFEA;
    color: #3B5998;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px #D8DFEA solid;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {

    background: #627AAD;
    border: 1px solid #627AAD;
    border-bottom: none;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    }
```

Comment: I just tried it in Firefox and IE8 and apart from the rounded border on the calendar header, they look the same to me. Can you provide a screenshot of the issue as you experience it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you mean that cells go outside the main box: I think it's because the Windows-based system (with IE) is missing Lucida Grande, and render it with Tahoma instead that has a different letter spacing. It looks the same in Firefox/Win as Bazzz said.

Search Google for Lucida Grande and try with it, or change the css in order to use Arial instead:

in jquery.ui.theme.css, around line 17:

```
.ui-widget {
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    ...
}
```

or just make the whole calendar widget a little larger:

in jquery.ui.datepicker.css, line 10:

```
.ui-datepicker { width: *18em*; ... }
```

hope it helps.

Comment: This is long dead, but I found it so I figured I'd add a note that installing a font is not really a solution because users (who might be on your problem browser) aren't going to install a font.

The CSS portion of this answer is the right way to fix this problem.